# How to assign more than one file type in VS Code

Tags: vscode-extensions

I'm working on a VS code extension which 'augments' a particular language - specifically it's for textmate grammars, which can be written in JSON format. I want to enable the extension for `.tmlanguage.json` files but without disabling VS Code's support for `.json`.
In `package.json` I have

```
 "languages": [
      {
        "id": "json-tmlanguage",
        "extensions": [
          ".tmLanguage.json",
          ".JSON-tmLanguage"
        ],
        ...
      }, ...
]
```

and

```
 "activationEvents": [
    "onLanguage:json-tmlanguage",
    ...
  ],
```

This activates when a `.tmlanguage.json` file is opened but seems to prevent normal JSON processing (e.g. Shift-Alt-F Format Document)

I don't want the tmlanguage stuff to activate on any JSON though, just the ones with the specific extension.

Comment: At the same time, it can be a few extensions installed for formatting json. User can switch language mode in the right bottom of the editor.

Comment: I agree that it has always been possible to switch language mode 'manually' but I hoped there would be a way to do better than this. I've been told about https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/198583 which may be the solution, when it gets into the released version of VSCode.